# Ajax 500 Server error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I get:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/goughChallenge/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

In the console when I click on a button... Ive looked at other threads but I can see an issue with my code. Could someone enlighten me?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// When document has fully loaded

$( function() {
    var locationForm = $( '#locationForm' );
    var results = $( 'div#result' );
    var formMessage = $( 'div.form-message' );
    var inputFields = $( 'input.required' );
    var submitButton = $( 'button.btn-submit' );

    $( locationForm ).submit( function( eve ) {
        eve.preventDefault();
        eve.stopPropagation();
        // Disable button
        submitButton.attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
        submitButton.addClass( 'disabled' );
        var currentLoc = $( '#currentLoc' ).val();
        var destLoc = $( '#destLoc' ).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: locationAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': 'locationCalculate',
                'currentLocation': currentLoc,
                'destLocation': destLoc
            },
            success:function(data) {
               jQuery('#result').html(data);
           },
           error:function(errorThrown) {
               submitButton.removeAttr('disabled');
                submitButton.removeClass('disabled');
                if ( errorThrown.responseText !== '' ) {
                    $( formMessage ).text( errorThrown.responseText );
                } else {
                    $( formMessage ).text( 'An error occured and your message could not be sent.' );
                }
                console.log( errorThrown );
               }
           })
       });
    })
});
```

Below is where the vars are defined

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Location Distance Calculator
 * Plugin URI: https://www.tomwithers.me
 * Description: calculate the distance between two given user points
 * License: GPL3
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */
function distanceCalculator() {
    /**
    * Input form for user
    */
    ?>
    <form id="locationForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="locationForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="currentLocation">Current Location: </label>
            <input id="currentLoc" type="text" name="currentLocation" class="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="destLocation">Destination Location: </label>
            <input id="destLoc" type="text" name="destLocation" class="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="locationCalculate">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Calculate Distance</button>
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <div class="form-message"></div>
    </form>

    <?php
}
add_shortcode( 'Calculator', 'distanceCalculator');

function locationData() {
    /**
    * Pull the form fields
    */
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" ) {
        $currentLoc = urlencode( $_POST['']);
        $destLoc = urlencode( $_POST['']);;
        $data = file_get_contents( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$currentLoc&destinations=$destLoc&language=en-EN&sensor=false" );
        $data = json_decode( $data );
        $time = 0;
        $distace = 0;

        /**
        * Check If form has had data entered
        */
        if ( empty( $currentLoc ) OR empty( $destLoc) ) {
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Please fill out all fields.";
            die;
        }

        /**
        * Calculate the disatnce
        */
        foreach ( $data->rows[0]->elements as $road ) {
            $time += $road->duration->value;
            $distance += $road->distance->text;
        }

        $time =$time/60;
        //$distance = round( $distnace / 1000 );

        /**
        * Output the vaules
        */

        if ( $distance != 0 ) {
            echo "<div id='result-generated'>";
            echo "From: " . $data->origin_addresses[0];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "To: ". $data->destination_addresses[0];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "Time: ".gmdate("H:i", ($time * 60))." hour(s)";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "Distance: " . $distance . " Miles";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "</div>";
            die;
        } else {
            die;
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_locationCalculate', 'locationData' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_locationCalculate', 'locationData' );
```

Im unsure of whats wrong and Ive been staring at my screen for about an hour! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: where are `currentLoc` & `destLoc` defined?

Comment: Not the problem but... You're adding a `DomReady` event handler in a `DomReady` event handler. `$(document).ready(function() { $( function() { ... ` O.o

Comment: still no `currentLoc ` defined in javascript...I think you have variable names mixed up. Shouldn't it be `user_loc`?

Comment: Corrected that I now get an internal 500 Error... THis issue was because of variable names... Will update the question now

Comment: Why are you posting client side code when you've got a 500 error? Look at the response from the server, it should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @Adam The only response i get is 'POST http://localhost:8888/goughChallenge/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)'

Comment: Click on the request in the network tab of dev tools and looks at the response, or check your error log, or start die()-ing in your server side function until you find where the error is occurring. There's nothing SO can help you with here other than tell you to do some basic debugging.

Comment: Fix the typo in function name: `http_respone_code(400);`

Comment: @Adam Fixing the typo now outputs a failed to load resource... and nothing is in the network tab

Comment: @GuruTom - if I remember wordpress correctly. All ajax functions need to call `exit` at the end of them, otherwise, weird stuff happens. If your request's response is empty, then either turn on PHP error reporting, or check your server error logs.

Comment: @GuruTom - forget my `exit` comment, I see you're already using `die` at the end of  `function locationData()`

Comment: @Adam Yup -Its like its skipping straight to the `error:function(errorThrown)`

Comment: Do you indeed have this `urlencode( $_POST['']);` instead of `urlencode( $_POST['currentLocation']);` and `urlencode( $_POST['destLocation']);` in your code or it is just for example?

Comment: @MatveyAndreyev Spot on Found this just too! Thanks for the help gents